# S10e bricked, cannot get into recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, boot-loop, unbricking, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I tried to change the logo that shows at boot, but it seems that I messed up and now my S10e is stuck on bootloop. The logo does not show at all and it reboots every 3 seconds (you can tell by the startup vibration). I cannot get into recovery mode nor download mode no matter how I tried (since the boot logo is normaly shown before entering one of these mode). The phone was running LineageOS 20, with Lineage Recovery installed and was rooted with Magisk 27.

Is there anything I can do or it's the end ?

Thanks for your responses

Answer (score 2):

In the end, when the phone ran out of battery, the bootloop stopped by itself. Then I was able to enter download mode by using Volume-, Bixby then pluging the cable (I was wrong, the logo is skipped when entering download mode) to flash the stock firmware with Odin, which repared the boot logo. Now the phone is working again.